# I am new to Selenium, using Java(Eclipse), I am having issues figuring out the xpath when using firebug

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

When I use firebug I get back this as the xpath it gives me back this /html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/h3/a

I am unclear how to use this in Selenium Webdriver to click on a link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is well covered in the documentation.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations

However, because its a very simple answer, you'd simply do something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[5]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/h3/a"));
```

(Assuming `driver` is a valid WebDriver instance and I've omitted the `html/body` section - it isn't needed).

Answer (score 0):

Always try to simplify the xpaths, try using firebug with this xpath to see if it's unique, if not you'll need to be a little more specific.

```
"//h3/a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use xpath unnecessarily. It would make some problem in future. If there is no other way to locate that element as @Nora told try to simplify the xpath.

In your case you can use By.linkText,By.partialLinkText.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("linkName")).click();

driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("partialTextOfLink")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='LinkText']")).click(); //simplified xpath
```

You can use any of the above if there is no other attribute(id, name ..etc) available for that anchor tag.